# Is deleting every index individually the only way?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an array of pointers of a class data type `Pool` but deleting it as if it were an array does not work.

This is the code:

```
struct Pool {
    /* in reality, complicated stuff here */
    int size;
};

Pool* createLargePool() { return new Pool{100}; }
Pool* createMediumPool() { return new Pool{20}; }
Pool* createSmallPool() { return new Pool{5}; }

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    enum ePool{
        small,
        medium,
        large,
        last
    };

    Pool *pools[ePool::last] = {
        createLargePool()
        , createMediumPool()
        , createSmallPool()
    };

    //Individually works. 
    delete pools[0];
    delete pools[1];
    delete pools[2];
    //delete[] pools;// error. (assertion error?)
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

To my understanding, my line `Pool *pools[]` is creating an array of Pool pointers. And that is exactly what my IDE is saying I'm doing. I'm running the code without problems until I reach the delete statement.

for some reason `delete[]` causing me problems, but deleting each one individually does not:

What's going on and how can I get delete[] to work?

Comment: `pools` wasn't allocated on the heap (by `new`, etc.). It's a local variable on the stack. You can't delete it, unlike the individual `Pool` objects it points to.

Comment: You're not using `delete[]`, you're using `delete`, and what problems that introduces are entirely dependent on what is returned by the three functions we aren't privy to. If they're not returning something `new`ed, then they shouldn't be `delete`ed.

Comment: What do `create*Pool()` do?

Comment: @PaulRoub That's exactly where I'm going wrong. I didn't know that happened with making an array of pointers. I thought it would have made the array on the heap as well.

Comment: It looks like you're showing the version that *does* work, and that there's a version which tries to call `delete[] pools;`, but that's not shown here. Correct?

Comment: Just use a `std::vector` and forget about raw pointers and stuff.

Comment: or even just use `std::unique_ptr<Pool> pools[ePool::last] = { .... };` and let nature take its course for cleanup.

Comment: I got as far as _"I am trying to make an array of pointers"_.

Answer (score 7):

The only way to delete each element with a single command is to make it a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pool>>` and call `pools.clear()`.

All other solutions require you to loop over the elements and delete them individually.

---

Moreover, your `create*Pool()` functions should not return raw pointers. They should return **smart pointers**, for two reasons:

- Users will then *know* that they are responsible for deleting the pointer.

  (With raw pointers they'd have to look at the internal implementations and/or documentation to know that.)
- This makes memory leaks virtually impossible, because the user now doesn't have to remember to call `delete` somewhere, which can be very difficult to get right in a complex project.

So I'd recommend returning a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Pool> createLargePool() { return std::unique_ptr<Pool>(new Pool{100}); }
```

or better yet (in C++14):

```
std::unique_ptr<Pool> createLargePool() { return std::make_unique<Pool>(100); }
```

Now, even if you store the smart pointers in a raw static array:

```
std::unique_ptr<Pool> pools[ePool::last] = {
    createLargePool()
    , createMediumPool()
    , createSmallPool()
};
```

they will `delete` their managed pointer when the array goes out of scope.

Comment: I don't know who would downvote this but I like this answer a lot. I didn't know that there was a functionality like this that could do the deleting for you in one prior created function, `clear`. It is that the work of `unique_ptr` template? My only concern with this is how do I know it wont delete the memory of my pointer in other similar methods?

Comment: Probably because you did not answer the question.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew note that `clear()` allows you to clear a vector if you want to do something else with it, but if this were as in your example it isn't necessary to call clear if you're done with it.  When the elements are `std::unique_ptr` then they will be deleted when the vector goes out of scope.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew Yes, `clear()` calls each element's destructor, and the destructor of `unique_ptr` calls `delete` on its managed pointer.

Answer (score 4):

> *"What's going on and how can I get `delete[]` to work?"*

Of course `delete[]` or `delete` without a prior `new[]` or `new` statement *doesn't work*.
Calling either form of `delete` in case the memory wasn't allocated dynamically, raises undefined behaviour.

Comment: There isn't any `delete[]` in the posted code. You're confusing `delete a[i]` with `delete[] a`. Oh, within the edit limit on this comment the OP added a *comment* with a `delete[]` in it. Well.

Answer (score 4):

You would use `delete[]` if you were creating a dynamic array of `Pool`s. But what (it looks to me like) you're doing here is creating a *static* array of pointers to dynamic `Pool`s. So, rather than `delete[]`ing the whole thing as though it were a dynamic array, which it isn't, what you need to do instead is `delete` each individual pointer in the array, as you inadvertently discovered.

Note, however, that deleting each element explicitly is verbose and fragile; better to loop through them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ePool::last; ++i)
    delete pools[i];
```

or, even better, like this:

```
for (Pool *p: pools)
    delete p;
```

Answer (score 4):

> To my understanding, my line `Pool *pools[]` is creating an array of Pool pointers.

Correct.  Specifically, a *local static array* of 3 `Pool*` pointers.

> for some reason `delete[]` causing me problems, but deleting each one individually does not

You are not allocating the array with `new[]`, so you cannot free it with `delete[]`.  It lives on the stack, not on the heap, and thus will be reclaimed when the array goes out of scope.

However, your array elements are pointers to dynamically allocated `Pool` objects, and those need to be freed with `delete` regardless of how the array is allocated.  Even if the array were allocated dynamically with `new[]`, you would still need to `delete` the individual `Pool` objects before freeing the array with `delete[]`.

> What's going on and how can I get `delete[]` to work?

If you really want to use `delete[]`, you have to use `new[]`:

```
Pool** pools = new Pool*[ePool::last];
pools[0] = createLargePool(Vector3i(12, 45));
pools[1] = createMediumPool(Vector3i(12, 45));
pools[2] = createSmallPool(Vector3i(12, 45));

...

delete pools[0];
delete pools[1];
delete pools[2];
delete[] pools;
```

Otherwise, you should use a `std::vector` instead of `new[]`:

```
std::vector<Pool*> pools(ePool::last);
pools[0] = createLargePool(Vector3i(12, 45));
pools[1] = createMediumPool(Vector3i(12, 45));
pools[2] = createSmallPool(Vector3i(12, 45));
```

Or:

```
std::vector<Pool*> pools;
pools.reserve(ePool::last);
pools.push_back(createLargePool(Vector3i(12, 45)));
pools.push_back(createMediumPool(Vector3i(12, 45)));
pools.push_back(createSmallPool(Vector3i(12, 45)));
```

To free the pools, you can use a loop:

```
// C++11 and later only...
for (Pool* pool : pools)
    delete pool;
```

Or:

```
for (int i = ePool::small; i < ePool::last; ++i)
    delete pools[i];
```

Or:

```
for (std::vector<Pool*>::iterator iter = pools.begin(); iter != pools.end(); ++iter)
    delete *iter;
```

Or:

```
void freePool(Pool *pool)
{
    delete pool;
}

std::for_each(pools.begin(), pools.end(), freePool);
```

If you are using C++11, you can use `std::unique_ptr<Pool>` instead of `Pool*` as the `std::vector` elements and eliminate calling `delete` manually (`std::auto_ptr` is not safe to use in STL containers, so don't try it):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pool>> pools;
...
```

However, since you have a small fixed number of pools, an array of `std::unique_ptr<Pool>` (C++11 and later) or `std::auto_ptr<Pool>` elements would be less overhead than a `std::vector`:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Pool> pools[ePool::last];
    pools[ePool::small] = createSmallPool();
    pools[ePool::medium] = createMediumPool();
    pools[ePool::large] = createLargePool();
    /*
    std::auto_ptr<Pool> pools[ePool::last];
    pools[ePool::small].reset(createSmallPool());
    pools[ePool::medium].reset(createMediumPool());
    pools[ePool::large].reset(createLargePool());
    */

    ...

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

BTW on a side note, you are creating your pools in backward order.  Your enum is ordered as small/medium/large, but your array is ordered as large/medium/small instead.  You need to swap `createLargePool()` and `createSmallPool()` around, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can't call delete[] on an array that wasn't allocated on the free-store with new[]. However, to answer the other aspect of your question that is posed, there is a better way to de-allocate everything automatically. Instead of an array, use a `std::vector<Pool> pools` and for each pool just do `pools.push_back( createMediumPool(Vector3i(12, 45)) )` etc...

Then, when pools goes out of scope, it automatically will call the destructor of every pool it contains, and all of the deallocations will happen automatically. As an added bonus, if you throw an error and take the "unhappy path" of your code at some point, it will still deallocate all of the resources automatically. This is the Resource Allocation Is Initialization (RAII) principle.

Comment: Presumably `createMediumPool` returns a `Pool*`, how do you expect to stick it into a `vector<Pool>`?

Comment: @Barry That's the problem I wanted to explain earlier. I'm trying to reduce the amount of copying and use straight pointers. I'll comment that in my code. (even though it should be assumed since it is an array of pointers)

Comment: @Barry @Lemony-Andrew Good point, I assumed you could edit the create pool function to return an object. But if you can't there is the option to make it a vector of unique pointers to pool objects. Also, if you are worried about the amount of copying, define a move constructor in pool and when you return the object from the create function, `return std::move(your object)` and that will reduce the amount of copying done without you having to pass around pointers.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew, to reduce the amount of copying in _modern_ C++, read about ___move semantics___. Only allocate things dynamically when you _must_, not when you want to avoid copying.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is allocated on the stack and does not need to be deleted. Stack based variables don't have to be, and in fact, should not be deleted. You only use delete to clean up heap based objects. Take this example (assume that you have a typical 32 bit system and that sizeof(int) == 4 bytes)

```
void foo() {
    int x    = 10;             // x on stack. consumes 4 bytes
    int y[3] = { 29, 42, 17};  // y on stack. consumes 12 bytes
    int z    = 11;             // z on stack. another 4 bytes

    cout << "Address of x    = " << &x    << endl;
    cout << "Address of y[0] = " << &y[0] << endl;
    cout << "Address of y[1] = " << &y[1] << endl;
    cout << "Address of y[2] = " << &y[2] << endl;
    cout << "Address of z    = " << &z    << endl;

    delete x; // NO! Don't delete a stack based variable
    delete y; // NO! Don't delete him either
    delete z; // NO! What's wrong with you.
}
```

The compiler generates code to manage stack based variables. Spaced is allocated on the stack at the start of the function, and is reclaimed when the function returns.

Objects on the heap follow different lifecycle rules. It is up to you to to delete them when you are done with them.

```
void foo() {
    int *x   = new int;      // x points to a 4 byte memory block on the heap
    int *y   = new int[3];   // y points to a 12 byte memory block on the heap

    delete x;   // Yes. Thank you.
    delete []y; // Correct.
}
```

Your code example gets a little complicated because you have a stack based array that holds heap based objects. You need to delete the individual heap based objects in the array, but not the array itself.

Here is an example that shows the various flavors

```
struct Pool {
   int x;
};

int main() {
    Pool p1[2] = {1,2} ; // array of objects. Everything lives on the stack.
    Pool* p2[2] = {new Pool, new Pool} ; // array of pointers. Array on stack. Pools in it live on the heap
    Pool *p3 = new Pool[2]; // heap based array of objects.
    p3[0].x=1;
    p3[1].x=7;
    Pool **p4 = new Pool*[2]; // heap based array of pointers to objects.
    p4[0] = new Pool;
    p4[1] = new Pool;


    // cleanup
    // none for p1
    delete p2[0];  // delete the heap based objects inside p2
    delete p2[1];

    delete [] p3;  // delete the heap of objects

    delete p4[0]; // delete pointers inside p4
    delete p4[1];
    delete []p4;  // plus the heap based array;
    return 0;
}
```